# Multiplying multidimensional matrices in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

When im trying to use tf.matmul to multiply a two Matrices with the shapes 
[41,22,512] & [512] I get the following Error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') 
with input shapes: [41,22,512], [512]..
```

I'd normally think that such a multiplication outputs a tensor with shape [41,22,1] or [41,22].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow : ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621652/tensorflow-valueerror-shape-must-be-rank-2-but-is-rank-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Matmul` wont work as the inner dimensions are not valid matrix multiplication arguments, instead you can do:

```
tf.reduce_sum(x * y, axis=2)
```

Comment: So we basically rebuild matrixmultiplication ourselves, interesting. Thanks!